# jdbc odbc DSN not found?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I developed a project using jsp-servlet, tomcat. I am trying to connect to database but it keeps on giving error

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Backend is MS-Access mdb. I have created DSN .

It was running fine in my machine before i re-installed windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Error : **Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

This usually means that your application can not find the data source name you have specified. This can be down to the following reasons :-

1. The data source name your have specified in your application is incorrect.
2. Your application can only use ODBC System DSN's and not user DSN's. Service based applications usually do not run as a user so they can only see System DSN's.
3. You are on a 64-bit machine and you have created a 64-bit DSN but not a 32-bit DSN. You need to create a DSN in the correct ODBC driver manager. If you need to create a 32-bit DSN on 64-bit Windows you can do this by running ODBCADM32.EXE from your SysWOW64 folder.